# Proof check. Standard form for alternating polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials

Let $R=A[x_1,...,x_n]$ for some commutative ring $A$. I am trying to prove that any alternating polynomial in $R$ can be written in the form
$$
\sum_{\lambda}c_{\lambda}a_{\lambda+\delta}\quad\quad(*)
$$
where $\lambda=(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ is a non-decreasing multiindex, $\delta=\delta_n=(n-1,n-2,...,1,0)$ and
$$
a_{\lambda+\delta}=\operatorname{det}(x_i^{\lambda_j+n-j}).
$$

What I have so far. Let $f\in R$. For any $1\leq i<j\leq n$ we have
$$
f(x_1,...,x_i,...,x_j,...,x_n)=-f(x_1,...,x_j,...,x_i,...,x_n)
$$
which means that if $f(x)=0$ whenever $x_i=x_j$. Therefore $(x_i-x_j)\mid f$. Since this is true for all such $i,j$ we have actually proved that
$$
a_\delta\mid f
$$
where $a_\delta$ is the Vandermonde determinant. Now, write $f=a_\delta p$ for some $p\in R$. In order to prove that the last expression can be written in the form (*) we only need to prove that for any monomial $x^\lambda=x_1^{\lambda_1}...x_n^{\lambda_n}$ we have
$$
x^{\lambda}a_{\delta}=a_{\delta+\lambda}
$$
and this is evident form the multilinearity of the determinant.

Is this ok? Also, does this actually work for all commutative rings?

EDIT: thank to darij grinberg's comment I think I get it now.

First, $x^{\lambda}a_{\delta}=\operatorname{det}(x_i^{\lambda_i+n-j})\neq a_{\lambda+\delta}$ (note the subscript of $\lambda$ is $i$ as opposed to $j$). So, this does not help (at least not in an obvious way).

Here is a proof that I have compiled:

Let $f$ be an alternating polynomial in $n$ variables. Write
$$
f=\sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}
$$
where the sum is over all multiindices with pairwise distinct components. Now, $$
(\forall\alpha,\forall\sigma\in S_n)\colon\quad c_{\alpha}=\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)c_{\sigma(\alpha)}
$$
The orbits of the action of $S_n$ on $\alpha$'s can be parametrized by strictly decreasing multiindices, that is, of the form $\lambda+\delta$ as above. Now, let $C_\lambda=c_{\operatorname{sort}(\alpha)}$. Grouping all monomials of the given orbit and then factoring out the coefficient, we get
$$
f=\sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}=\sum_{\lambda}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}C_{\lambda}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)x^{\sigma(\lambda+\delta)}=\sum_{\lambda}C_{\lambda}\operatorname{det}(x_i^{\lambda_j+n-j})=\sum_{\lambda}C_{\lambda}a_{\lambda+\delta}
$$

Comment: No, $x^\lambda a_\delta$ is not $a_{\delta + \lambda}$. You're overcomplicating the question, though; just compare coefficients. What kind of monomials can occur in $f$ ? And what relations must hold between their coefficients?

Comment: Yep, the new proof is correct! Except that you need to say a few words about why multiindices with non-distinct components cannot appear in $f$.